# Compiling C++/OpenGL in FreeBSD

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, freebsd

I'm trying to compile some C++/OpenGL source codes in FreeBSD-10.2-RELEASE.
To be specific, I'm following the instruction below:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/#Building_on_Linux

In step 6, I got an error message says:

```
In file included from /home/(my username)/Downloads/OpenGL-tutorial_v0014_33/external/glew-1.9.0/src/glew.c:32:
/home/(my username)/Downloads/OpenGL-tutorial_v0014_33/external/glew-1.9.0/include/GL/glew.h:1180:14: fatal error: 
      'GL/glu.h' file not found
#    include <GL/glu.h>
             ^
1 error generated.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
```

I installed some packages such as graphics/glew, graphics/glfw, math/glm, graphics/libGL, graphics/libGLU, etc, but it still fails.

What should I do to make them work?
Thank you.

Comment: Look at the `-I<path>` options passed to the compiler and check that there is one `<path>` such that `<path>/GL/glu.h` exists. Else, check that `GL/glu.h` can be found in the standard include directories of your compiler.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Okay, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FreeBSD OpenGL includes are located in `/usr/local/include`, so you need `-I/usr/local/include` flag.

To make tutorials link properly, you'd also need to replace

```
set(ALL_LIBS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    GLFW_303
    GLEW_190
)
```

with

```
set(ALL_LIBS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    glfw3
    GLEW
)
```

Note that you seemingly using headers from older libraries, this might cause more problems.

Comment: I added flags such as -I/usr/local/include, -I/usr/local/include/GLFW, etc and got some errors saying:

/tmp/tutorial15-9e4549.o: In function `main':
tutorial15.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
(...and so on...)
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can I have some more advice, please? Thank you.